# Android Intent for HTTP MP3 stream on HTC Incredible

Tags: android, android-intent

On the stock Droid and Nexus One, an intent like this:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://example.com/somemp3.mp3"), "audio/mp3");
```

works just fine and pops open the system music player to stream the file. But it doesn't match any activities on the HTC Incredible, causing a force-close when I call `startActivity` on it (I'm guessing due to missing intent filters in SenseUI's replacement applications). I'd prefer not to have to manage a MediaPlayer instance myself if I don't have to; does anyone know if there's a way to structure an Intent to convince the Incredible to play an MP3 stream over HTTP in its built-in Music or Streaming Media apps?

Comment: For what it's worth I wound up giving up and implementing a MediaPlayer-based activity to play the MP3s in app. I still think there ought to be a more elegant and simpler solution with Intents, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "audio/*" type. I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
context.startActivity(i);
```

You can also view video streaming, using "video/*" type.

This method worked on both Android 1.5 and 2.2, not sure about SenseUI compatibility. "audio/mp3" didn't work for me either, so it's not senseUI specific.

Comment: That was Fedor's answer... I still have to test it out on a SenseUI phone (which was the real sticking point -- for non-sense devices, "audio/mp3" worked fine anyways).

Comment: Funny, I thought using android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW made a difference, but it seems it works the same now. Did you try "(star)/(star)" for type?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar problem, and when i was into search, i've found this [link](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/) which helps you do some streaming from a mp3 source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's helpful if you're rolling your own MediaPlayer based solution to playing from a file on disk, but doesn't really answer the original question (how to open an HTTP MP3 URI in the system music player in SenseUI so you don't *have* to deal with all that MediaPlayer nonsense).

Answer (score 0):

to play audio file from server try this

```
try {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource("http://xty/MRESC/images/test/xy.mp3"
        );
    player.prepare();
    player.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
```

also in your manifest file use this permission..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

hope help you

this code piece originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441140/how-to-play-audio-file-from-server-in-android/7441192#7441192)