# how to play audio file from server in android

Tags: android

I want to download audio file from url and play that audio file in my device.how to implement this concept in my application.please help me

Thanks Friends

Comment: [Play an Audio-File](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+play+audio+file) | [Stream the Audio-File](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+stream+audio)

Comment: @Thanks your reply,i need play audio without download.

Comment: @John Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 16):

to play audio file from server try this

```
  try {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource("http://xty/MRESC/images/test/xy.mp3"
            );
    player.prepare();
                player.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

and if you want to download a .mp3 file form server then try this..

```
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    int count;

    try {

    URL url = new URL("url of your .mp3 file");
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();
    // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

    // downlod the file
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/somewhere/nameofthefile.mp3");

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;
}
```

also in your manifest file use this permission..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: what is publishProgress();

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:-

```
private void PlayFile() {
    try {
        mp.reset();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://soundcloud.com/storynory/the-valentine-witch-mp3/download.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(this, uri); // "this" refers to context
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you are required "Download MP3" code then i will post that code also.

Comment: Uri != String, please make sure