# Play audio files from server at first time and download it on SD

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that play different audio files,
I don't want to put audio files with application when user install it cause will have a huge size of apk file
so I want at first time user play any file to get it from url stream it and ask him if he want to download it so if he play same audio file while no connection available app will check if file on his SD and play it

Comment: Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441140/how-to-play-audio-file-from-server-in-android out.